# Rails jbuilder giving me undefined entries in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jbuilder

I'm building an array using jbuilder.

This is the tree.json.jbuilder code:

```
json.array!(@locations) do |location|
  if location.is_root?
    json.label location.name
    json.id location.id
    ...
  end
end
```

The json produced contains some "undefined" entries at the beginning:

```
[
   { },
   { },
   { },
   { },
   {
     label: "First Label",
     id: 1,
 ...
```

Is there some way to stop the undefined (blank) entries?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You  filter array elements within `#array!` block. To disable to stop blank entries, you have to make selected array first. Then build json content.

```rb
json.array! @locations.select{ |location| location.is_root? } do |location|
  json.label location.name
  json.id location.id
  ...
end
```

However the order of above solution is O(2n), even though previous(your) solution is O(n).
If you are stick to computation speed in server side, use previous one and handle json data in client side correctly.